# Google play dependency in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I am currently maintaining an older android app and I am having some problems with dependencies in build.gradle

What is the diference between:

```
compile 'com.google.android:google-play-services:4.1.32'
```

and

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:google-play-services_lib:4.1.32'
```

I have both dependencies in the build.gradle. Is it ok if i put

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

and remove other two dependencies?

Comment: check https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: just use compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

Comment: Yes, I already checked that. But i want to know if there is any difference between 'compile 'com.google.android:google-play-services:4.1.32'' and 'compile 'com.google.android.gms:google-play-services_lib:4.1.32''? Is this second one necessary? Probably, 'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'' can replace both...

Comment: There are no basically difference in between them ,services_lib probably old version (i am not sure). For better approach you should use 7.5.0

Comment: Thanks! Is it normal for gradle synchronization to last more than 2 hours? I have about 17-18 dependencies...